# RN Android Build Issue - Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: build, build.gradle, react-native

My client app is already published on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wofa) and it crashes

It maybe a stupid behavior from me , when I noted it works well for IOS,

I quickly deployed it for Android and published it

I tried to run it in my development environment using

> sudo react-native run-android

it makes the below error

[image]

What's the potential errors ?

I'm using MAC High Sierra

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "WOFA",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.10",
    "is-email": "^1.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "~5.5.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-grid-list": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-paypal-lib": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.5.1",
    "react-native-touchable-safe": "^1.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

the packages which need native linking are : [react-native-firebase , react-native-gesture-handler , react-native-image-picker , react-native-paypal-lib , react-native-svg]

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error on Windows 10.
In my case the culprit was node v.12.
Uninstall node and install LTS version of node.
(Currently node v.10.16.0)
Best Luck.